# Attaching text box to tikzpicture (syntax tree)

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, linguistics, syntax

I'm looking to attach some text to a specific node in this syntax tree with an arrow. Currently, I can't get the text to span over multiple lines, so it just cuts off once it reaches the right margin. Here is my code so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={stealth-,shorten <=0.5pt},
            Fit/.style={draw,inner sep=0.2pt,fit=#1},sibling distance=1em]
            \Tree[.\textbf{T} 
             [.\node(not){\textbf{not}};
             ]
             [.\textbf{F}
                [.\node(T){\textbf{T}}; \edge[roof]; \node(T){the circle 
                 \dots}; ]
                [.\node(and){\textbf{and}};] 
                [.\node(F){\textbf{F}}; \edge[roof]; \node(FO){it is the 
                 long \dots}; ] 
             ]
            ]
            %
            \node[Fit=(F)(FO),pin=right:{\textbf{Because something in the 
                 situation shown is perpendicular to the dotted line, 
                 namely the short solid line, but the long solid line 
                 isn’t perpendicular to the dotted line.}}]{}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[image]

I'd also like to make the text smaller, if possible.

Comment: Try `pin={[text width=4cm,font=\bfseries]right:{Because something in the 
                 situation shown is perpendicular to the dotted line, 
                 namely the short solid line, but the long solid line 
                 isn’t perpendicular to the dotted line.}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to make the code fragment compilable by including it into a complete document.